# Issues - Using RS.exe to set up SSRS subscription - Sharepoint Integrated Mode

Tags: sharepoint-2010, reporting-services

I am trying to create an SSRS report subscription for email through rs.exe utility by creating a rss script.

Given below is the command that I am executing in the local development environment for creating a subscription for the report using rs.exe utility

```
C:\>rs -i C:\TestSub.rss -s http://servername/reportserver_mssqlserver2008 -e mgmt2005
```

This works fine in the local development environment. “The command completed successfully" message is generated without any error and the report subscription appears under the “My Subscription” section of the report manager. SSRS is configured in native mode in the local development environment.

However, issue occurs when they try to do this on the actual development environment, where SSRS is installed in "SharePoint Integrated Mode”. I execute the following command there

```
D:\>rs -i D:\TestSub.rss -s http://servername/reportserver_mssqlserver2008 -e mgmt2010
```

Here also the command executes successfully and an entry is being added in Subscriptions and Schedules table in the "ReportServer" Database. However, the issue is that even if the entry is being added in the above mentioned tables of the "ReportServer" database, the "Manage Subscription" option is not displaying the subscription.

Could somebody throw light as to what could be going wrong?